# FilePath not found in ionic-native

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I've installed the following plugins:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-filepath
```

When I run ionic build, FilePath doesn't seem to be found.

I have the following import statement in my .ts file

```
import { Camera, File, Transfer, FilePath } from 'ionic-native';
```

But FilePath is not defined in ionic-native.

I'm using Ionic 2 Version : 2.1.13 and Cordova Version : 6.4.0

I get the following error:

```
~/workspace/ionic/tracks-driver(master :heavy_check_mark:) ionic build

ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build /Users/cnadig-cc/workspace/ionic/tracks-driver
ionic-app-scripts build

[09:36:09] ionic-app-scripts 0.0.45 
[09:36:09] build prod started ... 
[09:36:09] clean started ... 
[09:36:09] clean finished in 8 ms 
[09:36:09] copy started ... 
[09:36:09] ngc started ... 
[09:36:09] copy finished in 112 ms 
[09:36:22] Error: Error at /Users/cnadig-cc/workspace/ionic/tracks-driver/.tmp/pages/loads/loads.ts:4:34 
[09:36:22] Module '"/Users/cnadig-cc/workspace/ionic/tracks-driver/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/index"' has no 
exported member 'FilePath'. 
[09:36:22] ngc failed 
[09:36:22] ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[09:36:22] Error: Error

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:build" "--"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm v4.0.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build: ionic-app-scripts build
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! ionic-app-scripts build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /Users/cnadig-cc/workspace/ionic/tracks-driver/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete .tmp (/Users/cnadig-cc/workspace/ionic/tracks-driver/.tmp) and node_modules and run npm install again.

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you check manually if /Users/cnadig-cc/workspace/ionic/tracks-driver/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/filepath is there also on index.d.ts

Comment: No file like "filepath" exists in that directory. Didn't quite get what / where I need to check for index.d.ts. What about index.d.ts ?

Comment: @ChaiNadig `index.d.ts` is a description typescript file. This tells Typescript what to export and where to find it. If it doesn't exist, you won't be able to import an exported function/component

Comment: https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic-native/-/ionic-native-2.2.7.tgz get this and replace with your ionic-native inside node_modules